# How to reinitialize tensorflow variables?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In tensorflow 1 i used to run tf.global_variables_initializer() in order to (re)-initialize all the variaibles in graph. I have been away from tensorflow for a while and i dont see a method that could reinitialize the variables. I am running the [sequential tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/quickstart/beginner.ipynb) and i would like to be able to call model.fit many times without it warm starting on previous progress which it is currently doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `tf.keras` API, you can get/set weight values of a Model object by using the `get_weights()` and `set_weights()` methods.

See the perhaps simplistic example below:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(3,)))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd")
initial_weight_values = model.get_weights()  # <-- Remember the initial weight values.

num_examples = 100
xs = np.ones([num_examples, 3])
ys = np.zeros([num_examples, 1])
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10)

model.set_weights(initial_weight_values)  # <-- Restore the weight values to the initial ones.
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10)  # <-- The new fit() call should start from a high loss value like the one in the previous fit() call.
```

Caveat: This method re-initializes the weight values to *exactly the same value* every time. If you want different values each time, you can use something like `numpy.random` to generate values that have the same dtype and shape as `initial_weight_values`.